# Как реализовать обмен данными Python скриптом и консольным приложением

Tags: python

Решил заняться нехорошим делом - написать шахматного помощника для онлайн шахмат. Возникла необходимость работать с UCI протоколом движка. Сам движок запускается в "командой строке":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

принимает команды и выдает результаты там же. Так вот сам вопрос: как реализовать постоянный обмен данными между Python и движком? Есть ли возможность вбивать команды питоном, а не клавиатурой, и так же напрямую получать результаты - строки которые пишет движок, питоном?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Нашел [ответ на английском языке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341882/how-to-communicate-with-a-chess-engine-in-python)